# Java Resizable Bit Array?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a bit stream which spits one bit at each time, and the stream can stop at any time. What is the idiomatic way to record the output? Assuming my main usage for this data structure is to convert it to 8-bit block ASCII string later. `List<Boolean>` doesn't sound right because it's messy to convert to 8-bit block bit array. `BitSet` can't grow dynamically. `List<Char>` having a problem when the stream stops after spit bits whose number is not a multiple of 8. Any ideas?

Comment: Create your own class that uses a byte array.

Comment: A `BitSet` is quite useless: since a set can only contain each value once, this would imply that the set is either empty, contains zero, one or both.

Comment: I would use `List<Char>` or `StringBuilder` and buffer the incoming bits in a `byte`, turning it into a character whenever the byte fills up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply construct a BitList using an `long[]` array and an integer `nBits` that keeps track of the number of bits:

```
public class BitList {

    private int nBits = 0;
    private long[] data = new long[2];

    //0 or 1
    public void add (byte data) {
        if(nBits >= 64*data.length) {
            long[] newdata = new long[2*data.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                newdata[i] = data[i];
            }
            this.data = newdata;
        }
        data[nBits/64] |= data<<(nBits&0x3f);
        nBits++;
    }

    public byte get (int index) {
        long val = data[index/64]>>(index&0x3f);
        return (byte) (val&0x01);
    }

    //and so on.

}
```

---

Or you might wait until the system has spit out a multiple of eight by packing them into bytes:

```
public class Packer {

    private byte data;

    public byte getData () {
        byte result = this.data;
        this.data = 0;
        return result;
    }

    //only last bit counts (thus bit is 0 or 1)
    public void addBit (byte bit) {
        this.data <<= 0x01;
        this.data |= bit;
    }

}
```

In that case the `Packer` can be used to ease the implementation since you can use an `ArrayList<Byte>` and use an integer to keep track of the number of bits (without having to implement `add`/`remove`/etc. methods yourself.

Comment: Sadly, Java doesn't support unsigned variables... You could use just a `long`.

Comment: @CommuSoft "Or you might wait until the system has spit out a multiple of eight by packing them into bytes" What if we only have 7 bits? Then we need to keep extra information about how many bits we have otherwise how do we know if the right half of 0b10110000 is really 0b0000 or the stream only spits out 4 bits?

Comment: Indeed, but the packer can be used well to maintain an internal `ArrayList` such that you don't need to implement `add` and `remove` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a ByteBuffer.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

```
List<Byte>
```

This would most fluidly convert into a byte string, and the bits in each byte are identifiable.